# PostgreSQL: Change the origin for geometric types to upper left corner

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with **Postgresql** with imagery data.  We normally have the 0,0 as the upper left corner of the image.  When I try to store BOX objects in a table **Postgresql** is sorting the first and second parameters so the origin is the lower left.  Is there anyway to change where **postgresql** things the origin should be?

I'm using Posgresql 9.3.  The query would be something like 'INSERT INTO table (bbox) VALUES('(0,100),(100,0)')'

I would like:

- upper left =0,0
- upper right =0,100
- lower left = 100,0
- lower right = 100,100

what gets put into the database is: (100,100),(0,0). so it is 90 degrees off.

Comment: I think you forgot to include most of your question. Please edit it and add: PostgreSQL version, **SQL query text**, **exact text of any error messages or unexpected output**, sample data to go with the queries and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: ... though in this case it just sounds like you need to do a y-axis co-ordinate space transformation on load and store.

Comment: That sounds like it might work... i can't find anything online searching for y-axis space transformation and postgresql.  Is this something built into postgresql or something need to do by hand?  Can you point me at something that show how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Negating the y axis on load and store do what you want? `SELECT box ('(0,-100),(-100,0)')` ?

Comment: I just tried that and it puts "(0,0),(-100,-100)" in the database.  I don't think this is going to work.  It seems like the way postgresql is doing this it is taking the minX and minY for the LowerLeft.  I want the max X and min Y for the Lower Left.

Comment: Oh, that was negating both axes, sorry. Try `SELECT box ('(0,-100),(100,0)')`, i.e. negating only the y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negate the y axis when storing, and negate it again when loading. That should transform your co-ordinate space (origin 0,0 at top-left) to PostgreSQL's (origin 0,0 at bottom left) by mirroring it across the x axis.

```
regress=> SELECT box ('(0,100),(100,0)');
       box       
-----------------
 (100,100),(0,0)
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT box ('(0,-100),(100,0)');
       box        
------------------
 (100,0),(0,-100)
(1 row)
```

Do this consistently and all your in-database work with geometries will still be fine and consistent.

Alternately, just let Pg store the boxes how it wants. The same box is represented either way, and you can do whatever you want with it when you load it.

Comment: This is not right either.  The corner point numbers should not change it is just which point is the upper right and lower left that are getting switched.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you are right with it should not matter, because the corners are still the same. I was worried that things would get messed up if we put in a polygon (which does not reorder the points) and did one of the geometry functions like overlap that the answer would be wrong. But i don't think that is the case. My code just needs to realize postgresql will return the Lower Right and Upper Left in that order